# Why doesn't Apache Shiro's [anon] Filter work correctly?

Tags: apache, jsf-2, shiro, adminfaces

I tried to use authentication with Apache Shiro on my project, but without succes. I can't discover where is the trouble. I need only that whoever user access the page /pages/principal/products.xhtml directly, choose the product to buy and then be redirect to /purchase.xhtml to finish the purchase, but in my case all requests that I try are redirect to /login.xhtml page. Does anyone have any suggestions? code below. thanks!

```
shiro.ini    
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
authc.successUrl = /index.xhtml

[users]
admin@faces.com = adminfaces, admin
user@faces.com = user, customer


[roles]
admin = *
customer = purchases

[urls]

/index.xhtml = anon
/pages/principal/products = anon
/login.xhtml = authc
/javax.faces.resource/** = anon
/logout = logout
/pages/purchase/** = authc
/protected/** = authc, roles[admin]
```

web.xml

```
...
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you need to change the line:
`/pages/principal/products = anon` to `/pages/principal/products.xhtml = anon`

You might also be able to use [permissive](https://shiro.apache.org/spring-framework.html#annotations-and-web-applications) filter too

Comment: hi @Brian, I modified my shiro.ini to:

Comment: /pages/principal/products.xhtml = anon, and I include [main] authcBasic.enabled = true [urls] /pages/principal/produtcts.xhtml = authcBasic[permissive], without success. Any other helps? thanks for all.

Comment: can you access the page when you remove the shiro filter?

Comment: If I comment the ShiroFilter in web.xml, nothing works anymore. If I exclude all information in shiro.ini [main] [users] admin@faces.com = adminfaces [roles] [urls] blank, any request are redirect to login.xhtml.

Comment: Have you tried adding the filter lines one at a time to isolate were the issue is?

Comment: Yes, first I tried with authcBasic filter, then I tried with only authc filter. I think that authc isn't recognize the line [urls]/index.xhtml = anon.

Comment: I'm not following, can you explain this a little more:
> I think that authc isn't recognize the line [urls]/index.xhtml = anon.

Comment: I'm changing my approach about this case. I'm trying use ShiroFilter in another level of folder like this: myproject/src/main/webapp/authenticated_pages.   <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/authenticated_pages/*</url-pattern>

Comment: but, now the project throws an:  org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException

Comment: sounds like you trying to access Shiro's info (something like user data) from the context of a request that is NOT on your newly mapped path of `/authenticated_pages/*` ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my trouble. I'm using now redhat PicketLink solution. It's uses a fluent java language to configure paths to secure and it has a lower learnig curve. I'm considering Apache Shiro a great API for security, but I have a little time to learn it. thanks for your helps @Brian Demers.